# Redis notifications

Tags: redis, notifications, publish-subscribe

I'm using Redis as distributed cache. I have different applications which listen only particular keys. For example:
App1 listen App1.*
App2 listen App2.* and so on.

And my applications using following pattern to receive notifications:
App1:  "*key**:*APP1.*"
App2:  "*key**:*APP2.*"

I need to send notifications only about set, del, expired, evicted events that is why I have tried to use notify-keyspace-events "AK". If works fine for me but in this case of "AK" configuration redis starts to send extra notifications like "expire" which I don't need.

So according to documentation http://redis.io/topics/notifications I have tried to implement custom property:

notify-keyspace-events "Ksxe"  to send only set, expired and evicted notifications. But in fact in this case I receive only expired notifications..

Questions:
1. Why I doesn't receive set and evicted  events?? Why I receive only expired events?
2. Is there any way to make redis send only del notifications??

I also have tried "Ks" but redis doesn't send notifications about set events
A     Alias for g$lshzxe, so that the "AKE" string means all the events.
"Kg$lshzxe" doesn't works correctly too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the "s" flag. It has nothing to do with the `set` command. It tells Redis to only send commands that alter keys of the *type* "redis set" such as `sadd` or a key of the Redis set *type* expiring.

Thus, in your example "Ksxe" you instruct Redis to send you a notification anytime a key containing a *Redis set* is evicted or "expired". The "Ks" options instruct Redis to only send you notifications on keys of the *type* "set" being altered, not when a *string* is created using `set` command. To translate that to english, you told Redis "tell me when a key of type 'set' is expired or evicted".

If you want to know when a key of the *type* string is created or altered using the `set` command, has an expiration added to it, setting an expiration immediately deletes the key, or is evicted, you need to instead use "K$xeg". The "g" is important because it catches use of the `expire` command itself, and the '$' indicates the string type.

Also note that the "g" flag will result in "expire" events, but an expiration event will be labelled as "expired", enabling you to tell the difference. If you don't care about the creation of a TTL on a key, you can leave off the "g".